# tgkill kills entire process instead of just the tid passed

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I have been trying to use `tgkill` to remotely kill a thread.  I know that
`pthread_kill` is recommended for this kind of thing because of there not being any glibc
wrappers for `tgkill` but, I will be making the kill call outside of the process.

I've made a small example here to show what has been happening.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define GETTID 224


void helper1(void);
void helper2(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t process_id, thread_id;
    pthread_t h1, h2;

    process_id = getpid();
    thread_id = syscall(GETTID);

    printf("Main Thread: (PID-> %d :: TID-> %d\n", process_id, thread_id);

    pthread_create(&h1, NULL, (void *) helper1, NULL);
    sleep(1); // slight delay in creating each thread.
    pthread_create(&h2, NULL, (void *) helper2, NULL);

    printf("Entering Main's loop\n");

    for (;;) 
        ;

    return 0;
}

void helper1(void)
{
    pid_t process_id, thread_id;

    process_id = getpid();
    thread_id = syscall(GETTID);

    printf("Helper1 Thread: (PID-> %d :: TID-> %d\n", process_id, thread_id);

    sleep(3);

    printf("Entering Helper1's loop\n");

    for (;;)
        ;
}

void helper2(void)
{
    pid_t process_id, thread_id;

    process_id = getpid();
    thread_id = syscall(GETTID);

    printf("Helper2 Thread: (PID-> %d :: TID-> %d\n", process_id, thread_id);

    sleep(3);

    printf("Entering Helper2's loop\n");

    for (;;)
        ;
}
```

Compiling the following after getting and passing tgid and one of the thread id's
that printed out.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define TGKILL 270


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long ret;
    int tgid, tid;

    tgid = atoi(argv[1]);
    tid = atoi(argv[2]);

    ret = syscall(TGKILL, tgid, tid, SIGTERM);

    if (ret != 0)
        perror("tgkill");

    return 0;
}
```

Calling the above passing both the tgid and tid ends with the entire process being killed instead of the expected outcome of just the tid being ended and the main process continuing to loop along.

Is this the correct outcome here and I'm just not understanding the use of `tgkill` or am I making some kind of error calling here?

Comment: What do you imagine should happen when you kill a thread?!

Comment: I was thinking that only the thread passed to `tgkill` would be killed and all others (including the main thread) left untouched/unaffected.

Comment: It seems tempting to the novice to think something like that, but if you actually think about it a bit more, that doesn't make any sense at all. Your program would no longer be in any kind of deterministic state that you could reason about. You cannot just "stop executing" a program by some magical outside means and still have the program itself somehow be able to reason about that.

Comment: Good point but, if there were checks in the application that were planned in anticipation of this kind of change or event I would imagine it could be dealt with.

Comment: Well, I will need to delve deeper into the underlying mechanisms that are involved with the process/threads to really understand this.  Thanks for helping clear up this bit.

Comment: We summarize that by saying that "cancellation is a cooperative process". Indeed, your code needs to allow itself to be cancelled if that's a feature you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man pthread_kill` (essentially a pthreads wrapper around the `tgkill` syscall):

> Signal  dispositions  are process-wide: if a signal handler is installed, the handler will be invoked in the thread thread, but if the disposition of the signal is "stop", "continue", or "terminate", this action will affect the whole process.

The "terminate" signal is delivered to the designated thread, but the effect is to kill the entire process.

Comment: I started to read through the source in `pthread_kill` but from this link on [tgkill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tgkill) I took this description to mean that **only** the tid passed would be affected.

Comment: @tijko: Pretty sure it doesn't say that. The designated thread is the one to which the signal is *delivered*, but delivery is unrelated to *handling*.

Comment: @tijko: The signal **is** handled in the designated thread, too. But handling entails terminating the entire process.

Comment: I was able to get what I was expecting out of `tgkill` by creating a signal handler to catch a signal in the helper threads(and break their loops).  I was thinking of other ways around this too, and the more I did, the more the comment from above made sense(considering the state of the thread).

Comment: @tijko: If you're willing to build cancellation into your threads, then there should be simpler ways than dispatching signals. A simple atomic flag somewhere should suffice, for example.